# Plotly : Heatmap color legend i subplot

Tags: python, plotly, legend, heatmap

I'm working in python with plotly, trying to have two heatmap subplot with a custom legend for each.
But here what I see with the following code :

```
import plotly


fig = plotly.subplots.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)

mat = np.array([[1,0],
                [0,1]])


fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(z=mat, colorscale='Bluered_r'), row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(z=mat*10, colorscale='Bluered_r'), row=2, col=1)

fig.show()
```

[image]

you can see that both legend are displayed at the same place.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: When I looked into it, the legend for each subplot seems to correspond from [plotly community](https://community.plotly.com/t/associating-subplots-legends-with-each-subplot-and-formatting-subplot-titles/33786).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's not what I'm looking for though. It would be working for scatter plots, but for the heatmap, the color bar legends on the right are merged on the picture I just showed. I'd like to unmerged them. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just found a solution hidden in the doc using the colorbar argument:

```
import plotly


fig = plotly.subplots.make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1)

mat = np.array([[1,0],
                [0,1]])


fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(z=mat, colorscale='Bluered_r',colorbar=dict(y=.8,len=.5)), row=1, col=1)

fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(z=mat*10, colorscale='Bluered_r',colorbar=dict(y=.2,len=.5)), row=2, col=1)

fig.show()
```

This would give:

[image]